# What to do if I found out the preprint paper missed a citation of others' work?

Tags: plagiarism, ieee

I recently found out my preprint paper (to be published in a journal) that missed a citation of others' work, the paper is just published online in IEEE Xplore? The sentences are rephrased, however, I forgot to give credit notice within the texts. I feel very badly about it. I know this is a plagiarism. I do not want to find the excuse for myself. I want to remedy it before I cannot. What should I do it now?

The paper I should cite is in the reference list of the bibliography. I did not cite it within the texts.

Comment: _I know this is a plagiarism._ - Are you sure you know what plagiarism is?  Because it's not clear to me from your post that it is.

Answer (score 8):

Contact the journal as soon as possible with the correction, and see whether they can change it before the paper is officially published.

When they had real (and not electronic) typesetting, you had to try to change the text as little as possible. That's still a good idea, although it's less important now.

If they can change it before it's published, that's ideal. If they can't, you can decide what steps to take after they tell you it's too late.

Comment: And of course, take more care in the future. Making it part of your normal work-flow is a good idea.

Comment: I found this in the guideline: "Unacceptable requests are those that alter the author’s original intent of the article, or that involves a possible breach of publications policy". I am afraid it is nouse right now.

Comment: This does ***not*** alter your original intent of the article. Something that alters the original intent would need to be much more substantial, like a change that adds an extra hypothesis to a theorem. This is just correcting your unintentional oversight of not including a citation.

Comment: Agree with @PeterShor.  Aggressively try and contact the journal to get this resolved.  Throwing up your hands and quitting at the first sign of resistance is not the way to deal with this.

Further, don't stop at the first no - make them tell you know 6–8 times before you back off [1].

[1] Diamond, Stuart.  Getting More: How to Be a More Persuasive Person In Work and In Life.  ISBN-13: 978-0307716903.

Comment: If you don't contact them, it _will_ be plagiarism. You cannot let this go and preserve your reputation. In the worst case withdrawing the paper is preferable to letting it go through unfixed.

Comment: I wish I can. But under the current guidelines, it seems no such mechanisms existed. https://pspb.ieee.org/images/files/files/opsmanual.pdf

Comment: I am afraid if I contacted them right now. They will still treat me as Plagiarism

Comment: Let me lay out the consequences. If the original authors are still working, they very likely will find your work. They very likely will notice their own work uncited.  They may very well complain. They have every right to complain. Now you have no real defense. Either you are sloppy or a plagiarizer. This isn't an option for you. If they reject your correction, you should withdraw the paper and fix it. If they refuse to do that as well they participate in the wrong, but the consequences will still come back on you. Just. Do. It.

Comment: I concur with PeterShor and Buffy. The only way I could see such an edit changing the author's intent is *if the author intended to plagiarize*. Hopefully that's not the case here (and if it is, maybe don't tell the journal...), so please just go ahead and contact them right away.

Comment: @Wayne: there is a window between when the article is first published online and when the hardcopy is printed when it might be possible for them to make changes. Nowhere do I see in the guidelines ***"It is absolutely unacceptable to make any changes whatsoever after the article is published online in IEEE Xplore"***. Where do you see this written? And what can you possibly lose by writing them and asking?

Comment: Even if the editors consider you a plagiarizer rather than just sloppy, it is far preferable to the situation in which your whole field considers you a plagiarizer. You made a mistake. There will be consequences of the mistake. You can't avoid all of them. But you want the consequences to affect your future as little as possible. Take the good advice being given here, uncomfortable as it is.

Comment: See https://ieeeauthorcenter.ieee.org/publish-with-ieee/author-education-resources/guidelines-and-policies/correcting-metadata-in-ieee-xplore/

Comment: Nevermind the written policies. You have an exceptional case. They will make an exception or they will not, but that is for them to decide. If you don't contact them they don't know there is a problem. But future readers of your paper are likely to know that you have behaved badly, though not in what way. Just. Do. It.

Comment: You are misreading that document. It says "Acceptable requests include, but are not limited to, an author name is either missing from or spelled incorrectly ..." Surely, they'd be willing to spell an author's name correctly even if your original submitted manuscript had it wrong. It also says "Unacceptable requests are those that alter the author’s original intent of the article ..." That isn't the case here. ***It doesn't actually address this specific request.***

Comment: Furthermore, that page seems to address the case of corrections after the original article has been published in hardcopy. They may be more lenient before it's been published. Write them as soon as possible with the correction. (And write the original editors who are handling your submission.) I am willing to bet they don't want to publish plagiarized material any more than you do.

Comment: Peter is right on this one, but perhaps it is worth emphasizing the **write to the journal *now*** bit. The more time you delay, the more work the journal spends doing typesetting work that might need to be re-done; contact them *before* they do the typesetting and they'll be much happier to do the change.

Comment: Should I contact staff editor first? According to the this link https://supportcenter.ieee.org/app/answers/detail/a_id/289/kw/correction

Comment: That's what it sounds like, from that web page.